# Can I always use variable-length argument lists instead of arrays in argument types whenever is a choice?

Tags: java, android

I changed the `withColumns()` method in this class:

```
public static class Options {
    public String table;
    public String[] columns;

    public Options withTable(String table) {
        this.table = table;
        return this;
    }

    public Options withColumns(String[] columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
        return this;
    }
}
```

so it receives *variable-length argument list* instead of *array*:

```
    public Options withColumns(String... columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
        return this;
    }
```

Now I can write both:

```
new Options().withColumns(SubjectContract.TITLE, SubjectContract.PHOTO);
```

and

```
new Options().withColumns(new String[] { SubjectContract.TITLE, SubjectContract.PHOTO });
```

But of course, `withColumns(SubjectContract.TITLE, SubjectContract.PHOTO)` is more readable.

So are there any disadvantages in declaring argument type as a *variable-length argument list*, not *array*, whenever is a choice?

Comment: Consider checking [Java varags method param list vs. array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405673/java-varags-method-param-list-vs-array) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so basically it is your choice :

with optional params you cannot enforce user to input the value, so user can leave giving any input and complier will not complain.

```
new Options().withColumns();
```

with list of string , you need to give at least one value , value can be null.

```
new Options().withColumns(null);
```

so it all depends upon your use case.In this case table will always have columns so passing a array of column will make sense.

Comment: You *can* easily enforce the user to input `n <= 3` values, for example with `methodDefinition(Object obj, Object... rest)` you can enforce at least one value.

Answer (score 2):

A vararg is simply syntactic sugar for an array: you still get an array, just like in the original version, but now the call can be written simpler, without the surrounding boilerplate `new String[] { ... }`.

Either way, you probably want to check for null and empty arguments, as a table without columns won't make any sense:

```
public Options withColumns(String... columns) {
    if (cols == null || cols.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Table without columns? Get out of here...");
    }
    this.columns = columns;
    return this;
}
```